# AES encryption typeerror

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need a very simple algorythm.
I got this error msg:
raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type  cannot be passed to C code

when try to run this code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

msg_text = 'test some plain text here'.rjust(32)
secret_key = '1234567890123456' 

cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB)
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(msg_text))

decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encoded))
print(decoded.strip())
```

Comment: It depends on the version which you are using the proper way might be below: crypt_obj= AES.new('Test some plain text here'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_ECB, '1234567890123456'.encode("utf8")) that might work it depends on your crypto version check out the documentation

Comment: It is working on Python 2.7.15rc1

Comment: Is it python3? I bet it's a Python3 issue converting from string to bytearray that's bugging you. Try converting inputs between string and bytearrays as inputs to functions like b64encode/decode or encrypt/decrypt

Comment: It is python 3 and I installed this module with "pip install pycryptodome" and with "pip install pycryptodomex".